# Asterisk - Trying to use call files to create a conference call between two dynamic numbers

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to setup an Asterisk system that will allow me to create a conference call between two dynamic numbers.

It seems I can use 'call files' to make Asterisk initiate the call without needing an incoming call - http://www.voip-info.org/tiki-index.php?page=Asterisk+auto-dial+out

This example seems to be what I'd need:

```
Channel: SIP/mytrunk/12345678
MaxRetries: 2
RetryTime: 60
WaitTime: 30
Context: callme
Extension: 800 
Priority: 2
```

I can generate this file with some scripting language and then place it into the Asterisk Call File folder. The problem I'm having is: How do I call out to two numbers and join them in a conference call?

The MeetMe plugin/extension seems to be what I need in terms of conference calling, I'm just unsure as to how I'd use the two together and join them.

Also, is it possible to have multiple 2-person conference calls at the same time? Is setting this up as simple as setting aside X amount of 'channels' in the meetme.conf?

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right lines - if you just want to connect 2 people you don't have any need for the meetme conferencing, just setup the following:

extensions.conf context to dial outbound (you may have similar already):

```
[DialOut]
exten _0X.,1,Dial(SIP/mytrunk/${EXTEN})
```

In your call file where 123456 is the phone number of person 1 & 654321 for person2:

```
Channel: SIP/mytrunk/123456
Context: DialOut
Extension: 654321
Priority: 1
```

That will make a call to person 1 and connect them to a context that dials person 2.

If you did want to call more than 2 people and conference them you'd need call files for each person, and you'd connect them to a context that joined them into a meetme conference.

Comment: You've made this seem much easier than I first anticipated. I'm very new to Asterisk so I want some confirmation on my setup here - All I need to do is setup my sip.conf file, create the extensions.conf file and add your one DialOut context and then use the Call File to initiate the call? That's it? o.O

Comment: If all you want is to connect two people together then that's pretty much it - you'll need to have some way of connecting to the outside world - a sip trunk or PSTN card, but it sounds like you've thought of that already.